# Integration of piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to understand why Mathematica is not evaluating a piecewise function, while it's able to evaluate each of the regions separately. This fails:

```
fx[x] := Piecewise[{{(1/2) a*E^(-a*x), x >= 0}, {(1/2) a*E^(a*x), 
x < 0}}] 
Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals}  && {a \[Element] Reals} && {a > 
0} && {t \[Element] Reals}, Integrate[fx[x], {x, -Infinity, t}]]
```

This works:

```
Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals}  && {a \[Element] Reals} && {a > 0}, 
Integrate[(1/2) a*E^(a*x), {x, -Infinity, t}]]



Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals}  && {a \[Element] Reals} && {a > 0}, 
Integrate[(1/2) a*E^(-a*x), {x, 0, t}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, in the definition of `fx` include the parameter "a" as an argument and write `x_` instead of `x` :

```
fx[x_, a_] := Piecewise[{{(1/2) a*E^(-a*x), x >= 0}, {(1/2) a*E^(a*x), x < 0}}]
```

If you now you tell Mathematica that "t" is real and that `a>0` there is no problem integrating fx:

```
Integrate[fx[x, a], {x, -Infinity, t}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, t \[Element] Reals}]
```

$\begin{array}{ll}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{e^{a t}}{2} & t\leq 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} e^{-a t} \left(-1+2 e^{a t}\right) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong for `Assuming`

```
Clear[fx];

fx[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {(1/2) a*E^(-a*x), x >= 0},
   {(1/2) a*E^(a*x), x < 0}}]

Assuming[
 {x \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && t \[Element] Reals},
 Integrate[fx[x], {x, -Infinity, t}]]
```

> Piecewise[{{E^(a*t)/2, t <= 0}}, ((1/2)*(-1 + 2*E^(a*t)))/E^(a*t)]